# Google map not responding on android's native browser after 4-5 times zoom in and/or area navigation

Tags: google-maps-api-3, icefaces

I have developed a mobile site using Icefaces-mobile framework in that I want to search the things based on area zoomed in on the mobile screen, for this users can zoom in/out & navigates the area but the problem is after doing zoom in/out/navigations 4 to 6 times browser becomes unresponsive. I think it must be problem with browsers capability of handling/execute the javascript(correct me if I m wrong).
I have generated latest API key for map using some standers steps given by google on their forum.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Sounds like a massive memory leak due to poor coding.

Comment: Thanks for reply. My code is as follows:-[code]<mobi:contentPane id="poolSearchPane"> 
<div id="mobile_map" style="height:324px; width:100%"></div>
<script>createMap();google.maps.event.clearListeners(map, 'click');</script>
[/code] 
And javascript function is:
[code]var map;function createMap(){
var mapOptions = {
  center: new google.maps.LatLng(19.08, 72.88), //Mumbai
  zoom: 12,
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };
 this.map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("mobile_map"),mapOptions);
    
 }[/code]

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your code. As you say it must be problem with browser, or maybe with the device on which it is running.

Answer (score 0):

The stock Android browser does suffer from serious limitations, and it could be device performance limitations, as the previous poster mentioned. But you should also be careful that you're not inadvertently causing a memory leak in your own JavaScript. Are there DOM updates from Ajax interactions being generated during this? Check the Android LogCat messages to see the ICEfaces/ICEmobile logging which will show the updates. Check to ensure that if you're custom function is being re-run that you're not causing a memory leak there. If not, I doubt there's an issue with the GMap code and it's likely just a device limitation. Perhaps also put your gmap code in a separate HTML page without ICEmobile and see if you still have the problem.

Comment: Thanks Philip. Actually I have tested it on different devices, it is working fine in some where in some not. It must be depend on device performance. No, there aren't any DOM updates in code. Haven't check LogCat messages yet(don't know how to do it) will check and update to this post.